# Port Forwarding through SSH with Proxy

Tags: ssh

I am able to SSH into my bastion host using following command.

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:7890 %h %p" user@<bastion_server> -p 22222
```

Now I would like to perform a port forwarding to a server (IP address X.X.X.X) in private network such that I can view a webpage hosted in this server.

I tried following command but it returned `client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe` after I enter MFA code.

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:7890 %h %p" user@<bastion_server> -p 22222 -N -L 9200:X.X.X.X:443
```

[image]

What's the correct command to use? Thanks.